# Ubuntu 19.10 upgrade has destroyed my laptop. Is there any way to recover?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a Dell XPS15-9560 laptop running Ubuntu 19.04. I did the upgrade to 19.10 and it has left my laptop unusable.

The upgrade at some point left me with a black screen and a solid white cursor in the upper left of the screen. It had been in that state probably for hours. I restarted the laptop and got the Ubuntu splash screen and a wait cursor. I thought it would continue from that state but it's still flashing the wait cursor after 10 hours.

Is there any way to recover from this?

Comment: Can you reboot and get to the GRUB menu (advanced options for Ubuntu)?

Comment: No.  All I get is the splash screen with wait cursor.  There are a lot of error messages that scroll by before the splash screen comes up.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the problem is that 19.10 will not boot on the Dell xps15-9560. I've done a fresh install of 19.10 from a bootable USB stick and get the same problem.

Ubuntu needs to fix this, or pull 19.10.